# phpmyadmin did not work when change from higher version to 5 in apache2 using ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-20.04

ubuntu 20.04 and using Apache/2.4 version
I have multiple PHP versions. 8.1,8.0,7.4,.....7.0
And now I installed PHP version 5.6. when I disabled the higher version using the command `sudo a2dismod PHP*` and then run this command to enable the PHP version 5.6 using this command's `sudo a2enmod php5.6` after that my PHPMyAdmin did not work and showed this error.`This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500`.
I search a lot over the last two days. and try multiple queries.
when I change the version to PHP 5.6 then I have a project that required PHP version 5.6 that project runs successfully and generates the database error which means PHP 5.6 is running correctly.
also checked apache2 configuration files but did not understand the actual error.
also, cross-check the PHP version packages. below I am sharing a google photos link to share the php_info() screenshot of version 5.6 and version 7.4.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/PLoPWRAyyhh9xVo98

Search on Google for a lot of articles and StackOverflow questions and apply the recommendations.

Comment: 500 is an internal server error. Look into server logfiles to get more informations

Comment: "_Since release 5.0, phpMyAdmin supports only PHP 7.1 and newer._" You probably need to install a version of phpMyAdmin that supports php5.6

Comment: thanks, @Jens for your time checking the logs of var/log/apache2 but that is empty. Did you specify where I found that error logs?

Comment: thank you @brombeer I am trying to install PHPMyAdmin that comfortable with PHP version 5.6.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by brombeer, **PHPAdmin** does not support PHP 5.0 since 2019 (version 5.0)

> 5.0.0 (2019-12-26)
>
> - issue #13896 Drop support for PHP 5.5, PHP 5.6, PHP 7.0 and HHVM
> - issue #14007 Enable columns names by default for CSV exports
> - issue #13919 Remove font size feature
> - issue #12373 Add Metro theme
>
> . . . .

From [Official Changelog](https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/index.php?route=/changelog)